# GitHub workflow set up job fails with the error Resource not accessible by integration

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

This GitHub Workflow worked fine in the last few months. But suddenly it became always fail with the error `Resource not accessible by integration`. This error occured in the set up job of the workflow.

[image]

It uses checkout@v2 action and another docker action that is defined in the repository itself.( see the following image for a successful job )

[image]

I checked the permissions of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Seems like every necessary permissions are already there.

[image]

What could be the reason for this error and how can this be solved?

Comment: It could be related to the Github Outage that occurred today (March 16) on Github Actions: https://downdetector.com/status/github/ Does it still happen?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes..It still happens. I reran the jobs but it still keep failing

Comment: Ok. Could you share your implementation or repo to try reproducing the issue?